Prove that a sequence of functions cannot converge to $0$ a.e. under certain assumptions on the integrals of $f_n$
I was scrolling through YouTube recently when I stumbled upon the following problem:
Let $\{ a_n \}$ be a bounded increasing sequence of positive numbers and let $\{ f_n \}$ be a sequence of Borel measurable functions acting from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, \infty)$ s.t. $\int_{[0, 1]}{f_n d\mu} = n$ and $\int_{[0, 1]}{f_n^2 d\mu} \leq a_n n^2$, here $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Prove that $\{ f_n \}$ cannot tend to $0$ a.e. on $[0, 1]$.
I tried to arrive at some contradicting inequalities using Egorov’s theorem together with CSI, but that did not lead anywhere. I really do not see how this can be proved. Any help?

The solution by @DavideGiraudo here goes along the lines of your initial attempt.

@Mittens, yes, thank you. It is kind of embarrassing that I was not able to make the last step of the proof. I was just using CSI too crudely and sloppily. But I guess I’ve learnt a nice lesson

Hint: Let $g_n=\frac {f_n} n$.  Choose $M$ such that $\int_{|g_n|>M}|g_n|\le \int |g_n|^{2}/M<\epsilon$ for all $n$  and note that $\int_{|g_n| \le M}|g_n| \to 0$ by DCT.
